# Group by two columns and count duplicate as 1 in Power BI

Tags: count, powerbi

I have two columns on a table (List) which has the following

List Table (Input) 
[image]

Output:
[image]

Moreover; I want to create a donut chart to get the output count of specific ERP: Xero and count the rest as 1 so it will be XERO/The Rest of ERP.

Answer (score 0):

Use Advanced groupby option in power query like below.

Note you should select both the columns by holding control key.

[image]

[image]

[image]